# How to make a Generator for Stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

i try to write a generator or i want to write all stored procedures(SP) in C# side. how can i do that? 
1) writing a sp generator OR
2) Coding all sps via C#  OR
3) Writing All data process (SP) via Linq

which one is best or your advise?

Comment: Stored procedures are by definition stored on the server-side.  If you write the SQL on the client-side, it's not a stored procedure.

Comment: What's wrong with the existing ORMs?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generator yourself, all in C# - if you search on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=stored+procedure+generator) you'll find quite a few articles and code samples (some quite old and outdated, however).

But you might also benefit from code generation techniques, such as T4 (Text Templating Transformation Toolkit) which is part of VS2008 and VS2010 and one of Microsoft's best kept secrets :-)

Check out:

- [How to use T4 to generate CRUD stored procedures](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/01/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-crud-stored-procedures/)
- [T4 templates for stored procedures](http://www.buildmotion.com/buildmotion-blog/09-06-15/T4_Templates_for_Stored_Procedures.aspx)

or you could also use a commercial code generators such as [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) and its available templates for CRUD stored procedure generation.

Answer (score 1):

if you have table and columns informations then you can develop a sp generator for sql server.

Your start point must be below queries;

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`  --get table information 
`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` --get table column information

Answer (score 0):

There is AutoSproc from MS. Your mileage may vary etc.

Links etc here in my answer to [TSQL - Parse Execution Plan to determine columns to be returned by a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256619/tsql-parse-execution-plan-to-determine-columns-to-be-returned-by-a-stored-proce/1256698#1256698)