# Does AutoSproc Scale Well?

Tags: asp.net, scalability, data-access-layer

We use AutoSproc as our DAL, not my choice, but it was there when I started working at my job. I was wondering if any one had any experience using AutoSproc with large web applications? I'm just curious if it would scale well as our application is growing and we might need to pop it into a web farm at some point.

If it doesn't scale well, what would you suggest then since there are several options out there.

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

2 previous answers (by me)

[TSQL - Parse Execution Plan to determine columns to be returned by a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256619/tsql-parse-execution-plan-to-determine-columns-to-be-returned-by-a-stored-proce/1256698#1256698)

[Are there any gotchas or good reasons not to use autosproc for stored procedure calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626933/are-there-any-gotchas-or-good-reasons-not-to-use-autosproc-for-stored-procedure-c)

We're not a big shop in terms of users, but it didn't work for us.